# Conditionally map two columns to one field with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, dictionary, conditional-statements, fluent

I have an NHibernate entity called Owner that has a SSN column and a TaxID column in the database, and I would like to conditionally map one of those two values to a more generic property on the Owner entity based on the value of a different property, StructureType. So, if the StructureType is "I", I want to map the SSN value to the generic property, and if its "C" I want to map the TaxID value to the generic property. Is this possible using Fluent NHibernate (or even regular NHibernate)? The Owner entity is a read-only entity, nothing will be written back to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this using a Formula in Fluent NHibernate:

```
Map(x => x.Identification)
.Formula("CASE WHEN StructureType = 'I' THEN SSN ELSE TaxID END");
```

(In my original post I said it was between 'I' and 'C' but is in fact just between 'I' and every other type)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a readonly property?

```
public string Identification
{
   get
   {
       string identification = string.Empty;
       if (StructureType.Equals("I"))
           identification = SSN;
       else if (StructureType.Equals("C"))
           identification = TaxID;
       return identification;
   }
}
```

Comment: That would work, though I believe I have found the way to do this in NHibernate, as I'll detail below in a moment.

Comment: I was able to solve this using a Formula in Fluent NHibernate:


Map(x => x.Identification).Formula("CASE WHEN StructureType = 'I' THEN SSN ELSE TaxID END");

(In my original post I said it was between 'I' and 'C' but is in fact just between 'I' and every other type)